# Communicate with a subprocess using pipes on other than stdout/stderr

Tags: python, c++, linux

This is how I fork/exec a subprocess and communicated with it (pseudocode):

```
int cout_pipe[2];
pipe(cout_pipe);
fork();
if (child)
{
  dup2(cout_pipe[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
  execv();
}
if (parent)
{
  File* cout_file = fdopen(cout_pipe[0], "r");
}
```

My question is:

I don't really want to read the stdout of my subprocess, I would like the subprocess to write on a file descriptor other than stdout. And, I'd like the above code to read from that file descriptor.

The subprocess is written in python, the main process in C++.

I am thinking I can change that line, from:

```
dup2(cout_pipe[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
```

To

```
dup2(cout_pipe[1],MY_OWN_RANDOM_FD_NUMBER);
```

And code the subprocess in a way that I write to MY_OWN_RANDOM_FD_NUMBER instead of stdout.

Is this a good solution? doable? How can I figure out a good MY_OWN_RANDOM_FD_NUMBER? Is there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want a specific fd, like standard out, there's no point in the `dup2`.  Just convert `cout_pipe[1]` to a string, and pass that as a command line argument to the child (in the `exec`).  On the Python side, pick up the argument from `sys.argv`, convert it back to an `int`, and use `os.fdopen` to obtain a `file` for it.

Comment: convert cout_pipe[1] to a string? so that means that pipe(cout_pipe) makes cout_pipe[1] a valid fd?. Also what's the best way of convertion itoa(cout_pipe[1]) ?

Comment: @Kam `pipe( cout_pipe )` puts the two fd for the pipe in `cout_pipe`.  The only reason you might want to use `dup2` is because you're not happy with the numerical value of the fd.  As for the conversion, any of the standard solutions will do the trick; if you do it on the child side, immediately before the `exec`, and your system has `itoa` (it's not standard), then even this would be acceptable; if you're using C++11, you can use `std::to_string`---just be sure to save the results to a variable with sufficient lifetime before calling `.c_str()` on them.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to dup the file descriptor in the situation you describe.  The call to pipe() already created the file descriptors that you need in the cout_pipe array.

Typically, the child process simply closes the read side of the pipe before exec'ing while the parent process closes the write side of the pipe.  The child writes whatever it wants to the write side and the parent either reads or otherwise monitors the read side of the pipe.

If your question is "How does the child process know the fd number after it exec's, then I'd say pass it as a execution parameter when you call execv() in the child process."

Something like:

```
int   child_pipe[2];
FILE *child_file;

void forkchild(void)
{
    int  ret;
    char child_pipe_fd_str[16];

    pipe(child_pipe);  /* TODO: check return value! */

    if (0 == (ret = fork())) /* child */
    {
        close(child_pipe[0]);
        sprintf(child_pipe_fd_str, "%d", child_pipe[1]);
        execv(my_python_script, child_pipe_fd_str, NULL);
    }
    else if (-1 != ret)  /* parent */
    {
        close(cout_pipe[1]);
        child_file = fdopen(cout_pipe[0], "r");
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Fork failed!");
        abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the above situation, when child writes to stdout, stdout was previously redirected to pipe, so the parent process can read the child's stdout just by reading from pipe. 
I would like the child to write not to stdout, but to another file, and the parent process can read it.

Comment: If you want to wrap the write side of the pipe in a FILE, then call fdopen(write_side, "w") in your child process after you exec.  The trick is to know the file descriptor # of the write side of the pipe in your child *AFTER* you exec.  One way to do that is to explicitly pass it as an execution parameter when you call execv().  Is that clear?

Comment: Ok so I should create a FILE after the fork, before the exec, then dup2(cout_pipe[1], this_files_fd), then pass the FILE's fd to subprocess as argument of the exec, and in python I write to this fd?

Comment: No, you should create the file structure *AFTER* you exec, inside your new Python process using os.fdopen.  The trick is to know what fd # you need to open.  You should pass that as an execution parameter to execv() in your child C process.  I'll post some code in my answer.